# SPFX - How to suppress TypeScript errors in the terminal so the app can compile?

Tags: spfx, typescript

I have tried using `// @ts-ignore` which removes the error from my IDE, but in the terminal the error persits so the app does not compile. Any idea how to get around this?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactable <  This Library is cuasing the TypeScript error when I add in the sort function from the documentation:

```
  <Table
      className="reactTable"
      data={this.state.documents}
      sortable={[
        'Name',
        'Scheduled Review Date',
        'Path',
        // @ts-ignore
        // tslint:disable-next-line
        {column: 'Column Name', sortFunction: function(a, b){
          return a > b ? 1 : -1;
        }},
        'Site',
        'Last Review Date'
      ]}
      itemsPerPage={7}
    />
```

> [09:16:17] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/kim/components/Kim.tsx(271,11): error TS2322: Type '(string | { column: string; sortFunction: (a: any, b: any) => 1 | 
> -1; })[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | string[]'.
> [09:16:17] [tsc] Type '(string | { column: string; sortFunction: (a: any, b: any) => 1 | -1; })[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
> [09:16:17] [tsc] Type 'string | { column: string; sortFunction: (a: any, b: any) => 1 | -1; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> [09:16:17] [tsc] Type '{ column: string; sortFunction: (a: any, b: any) => 1 | -1; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: What kind of errors? Add them (or some of them) to the question!

Comment: Are they not valid errors? Can you share examples?

Comment: @RuneSperre I have added examples :)

Comment: I think you must include more of your code -- how have you implemented the sort function in your table?

Comment: @RuneSperre I have added more of the code, but the library I'm using for the table will have the sort function on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking into the Table component and updating the interface to use any  `sortable?: any | string[] | boolean;` fixed the errors. Bit of hack but nothing else was working!

Final solution:

```
    {column: 'Scheduled Review Date', sortFunction: function(a, b){
      var dateA = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), dateB = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
      if (dateA < dateB) { // a comes first
        return -1
      } else if (dateB < dateA) { // b comes first
          return 1
      } else { // equal, so order is irrelevant
          return 0 
      }
    }},
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to both suppress the errors in the IDE and get the project to build by using `ts-lint:disable` as the first line in the file, while citing the exact rule(s) to disable, so something like

```
/* ts-lint:disable:no-any max-line-length */
import Something from 'something';

export default class Foo {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Not working sadly, /* ts-lint:disable at the top of the file should suppress the error buts it not